# Not able to add space in date time format parameter

Tags: sitecore-api

I am facing difficulty in displaying date field. It is not allowing me to send space in the format parameter.
For example if I use below code:

```
@Html.Sitecore().Field(Value_of_the_datetime field, new {format="MMM dd, yyyy"})
```

In the output it shows month only.

But if I choose a format like "MMMddyyyy"(basically without any space), it shows the full value.

Does anybody know how this issue can be resolved?

Comment: Are you sure it's not a styling issue? Have you checked the source of the page?

Comment: No Marek, this issue is more like a bug which might not have been in previous versions but it is in 9.3 for sure. Faced this issue while completing the training material and now in the project itself.

Comment: Indeed, I reproduced the same after upgrade 8.2 => 9.3. In would be nice to understand the root cause of this issue.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You should try the format like below -

```
@Html.Sitecore().Field(datefield, new {format="MMM\ndd,\nyyyy"})
```

Hopefully, this is will work for you.

Comment: You are awesome, thanks for your quick reply

Answer (score 1):

It's a known issue starting from 9.3.
The reference number you can provide Support with is 421731.