# Some date format in SXA is not displaying properly after migration

Tags: sxa

we are migrating contents from Sitecore 9.1 to Sitecore 10.0. however after we moved our contents, we encounter display behavior in some of the date formats. This is how the dates are displayed:

[image]

In the example above, only the day was displayed. so it appears in the "d M, y" format only the "d" is evaluated. same thing happened in other date formats, only the characters before the first space is evaluated. I checked the Date field and it is using a Date data type in the data templates. Both dates above is linked to the same Date field.

we can't debug the codes because the component is using the out-of-the-box features of Sxa.

anyone has encountered the same issue? any input will be appreciated.

Comment: can you check raw value for fields and compare if these hold similar format

Comment: raw value is in this format: 20200508T105600Z

Answer (score 1):

This post shed some light on my issue:
[Not able to add space in date time format parameter](https://sitecore.stackexchange.com/questions/24611/not-able-to-add-space-in-date-time-format-parameter)
this is known issue since Sc 9.3. If you are using SxA, you can use Scriban to display the date in Full view:

`{{ sc_field i_item 'Date' [ [ 'format', 'd\nM,\nyyyy' ] ] }}`